# How can I get the full width that a WrapPanel can have before it wraps to a new line?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the width that a WrapPanel can extend to before it wraps to a new line. The Width property of the WrapPanel only returns the current width. So lets say my WrapPanel has 5 children, but it can have 12 children before it wraps to a new line. When the WrapPanel has 5 children it returns only the width it currently has, but I want the width it has with 12 children without actually inserting 12 children.

How can I receive this information? My WrapPanel currently has a set ItemWidth if it is relevant. I also want that full Width to be like ActualWidth, i.e what is actually rendered. Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't used them before, but I imagine it's directly related to the width of the object that contains the WrapPanel

Comment: @RufusL I'm kinda new to WPF, I made a custom WrapPanel. Can I retrieve the parent's ActualWidth in code in the custom WrapPanel?

Comment: I don't know, it was just an idea in case you haven't explored it already.

Comment: @RufusL Alright thanks, will check if I can retrieve the parents width in my custom control

Comment: You could use binding and relativesource to search up the visual tree. You can write a lot of Wpf projects without needing to build a custom panel.

Comment: @Andy Yeah I know but I wondered if there was a way to get it directly in the code. Otherwise, I think I have to use multi bindings for my use case.

Comment: to do it simple why don`t you add dummy no of items for which you want size then  get the width and later remove the dummy data